# Digital Certificate Repository Integrity

Tags: certificate-authority, key-management

I am trying to figure out if there is an automatic way to determine if a digital certificate repository has been tampered with. Does anyone know of a way to do so?

Comment: There are several well known CA repos.  Such as Microsoft, Apple, Java, Mozilla. All use different storage technology. Could you change your question to show which of these you are most interested about?

Answer (score 1):

Short of asking the Certificate Authorities yourself (preferably with a secondary list of valid CRL and or OCSP download URL's lists) one by one I know none.
You could script that, or you could recreate the Repository and create a hash of it. Also checking if the checksums are valid can give you a clue (although it does not show a replaced certificate / added certificate)

TL;DR none that are fast & easy. only hand checking is available.